# Android context menu customization

Tags: android-layout, android

can anyone tell me if context menu can be customized (or altered) in such a way to use different item style (assuming that items are of same class)? I.e. one item has a black text color, other yellow, some other has a red background, etc...

I'm also interested if this can be done to existing menu programmatically or it can be set trough XML?

P.S. I tried various suggestions by using new factory and overriding view crate but that didn't worked (due to using android support library).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could show up anything you want just override menu button on click and show your very special menu/view whatever you want instead of built-in menu

Comment: Well, I know that but that wasn't my question. I asked the question because I don't want to reinvent the wheel every time I need a 'custom' feature:)